# How to wait until subscribes in loop had finished?

Tags: angular, typescript

My method

```
    onSubmit() {
        let answers1 = document.getElementsByName("answer");
        let answers = answers1 as unknown as HTMLInputElement;

        for (let i = 0; i < answers1.length; i++) {
            if (answers[i].checked) {
                this.dataService.getAnswerById(answers[i].value)
                    .subscribe((data: Answer) => {
                        this.sum += data["mark"];
                        console.log(this.sum);
                    })
            }
        }
        console.log(this.sum);
    }
```

I get all radioButtons from my document with name `answer` (values of this buttons are `AnswerId`). Then, if button is checked, I get answer by id with get method, then I take mark of this answer and add to a sum, to get whole score for a test.

`answers1` are radioButton elements.

How can I get final `this.sum` after loop had finished? I think, I can use forkJoin, but I dont now how to use it in loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

...

onSubmit() {
    // array of radio buttons
    let answers1 = document.getElementsByName("answer");
    let answers = answers1 as unknown as HTMLInputElement;

    const observables = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < answers1.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i].checked) {
            observables.push(this.dataService.getAnswerById(answers[i].value));
        }
    }

    forkJoin(observables).subscribe((data: Answer[]) => {
      this.sum = (data || []).reduce((res, ans: Answer) => res + ans.mark, 0);
      console.log(this.sum);
    });

    // at this point you cannot see this.sum as it collects async data
}
```

I used `Array.filter()` function to filter only checked answers and then `Array.map()` to create an array of Observables to be passed to `forkJoin()` function

Comment: I got 3 errors: 
`(TS) Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'Answer'.` ;
`(TS) Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'` ;
`(TS) Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Answer`

Comment: `answers1` are radioButtons

Comment: you are right I used `answers` instead `answers1`, I updated my answer with simplified solution. Please try it...

Comment: Thx, it works! but i have few questions: 1. Can you please explain me what is happening inside forkJoin method; 2. Do you know, why I can't use properties like `ans.mark`, but `ans["mark"]` is working? This is happening with all properties in my component.

Comment: 1) `forkJoin()` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) executes Observable functions in parallel, and resolves only when all functions succeeded, or rejects if any of functions errors. 2) as long as your `Answer` type / interface has `mark` property, TS should not complain about using `ans.mark`, please check `Answer` interface

Comment: My `Answer` has `Mark` property, it makes this more strange

Comment: And if I want to send post method with `this.sum` in parameters, I should do this in `forkJoin()` method?

Comment: Yes, only in forkJoin subscription you have all answers accumulated